# Spring facility to keep the java process running continuously?

Tags: java, spring

I have a java process that kick-starts several other java processes.

```
public class ROCServerEntrypoint {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    BeanConfigRegisterUtil.util.registerBeanConfig(annContext);
    ServiceInitUtil.util.initServerServices(annContext);
  }
}

public class ServiceInitUtil {
  public static ServiceInitUtil util = new ServiceInitUtil();
  private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceInitUtil.class);

  public void initServerServices(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context) {
    this.context = context;
    context.refresh();
    startServices(new ArrayList<Service>(fetchRegisteredServices()));
  }

  private Collection<Service> fetchRegisteredServices() {
    return context.getBeansOfType(Service.class).values();
  }

  private void startServices(List<Service> registeredServices) {
    Collections.sort(registeredServices, new ServiceOrderComparator());
    logger.info(">Initiating services...");
    for (Service service : registeredServices) {
      logger.info(">Starting service - " + service.getClass().getSimpleName());
      if (!service.start()) {
        logger.info(">Failed to start service - " + service.getClass().getSimpleName());
        logger.info(">Initiating shutdown...");
        shutDown(service, registeredServices);
        break;
      } else {
        logger.info(">Successfully started service - " + service.getClass().getSimpleName());
      }
    }
  }

  private void shutDown(Service failedService, List<Service> registeredServices) {
    for (Service service : registeredServices) {
      if (!service.equals(failedService)) {
        logger.info(">Shutting down service - " + service.getClass().getSimpleName());
        service.shutDown();
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

In order for the services to run continuously I need the `ROCServerEntrypoint` to be running continuously.
Tried these two approaches which work.

1. Start the ROCServerEntrypoint as a Thread.
2. More naively, run a infinite loop.

Alternatively, wondering if Spring has some cleaner solution for this.

Comment: yes using spring boot. But couldn't find how exactly. By default, the process  exits.

Comment: So you don't have any long-running services such as an HTTP or MQ endpoint? How are these services communicating with the outside world?

Comment: I have services like Apache Flume,zoo-keeper,kafka,hive that will be running continously.

Comment: Project yet in beginning stage.Input is by use of property files.Output by means of logs.

Comment: If the input is from property files, then there's no *reason* to keep it alive. When you get to the point where you add some sort of endpoint, that will usually take care of it.

Comment: Property files are only to provide metadata, for initialization.The services have to be kept alive to process any live data that will come in.For eg. Kafka has to be running always to publish and consume the information that may periodically come in.

Comment: Why not use out of the box scheduler? That's what they are meant for...

Comment: Dear negative voter. Kindly comment.

Answer (score -2):

Without additional info, the best way is to use infinite loop with `Thread.sleep` plus printing out a heartbeat after each sleep.

If you don't have any other dependencies in the project, there is no point in adding spring to it just to get rid of infinite loop.

Comment: Already pointed out in my question that i do not want to do this.

Comment: You wrote that you tried and wonder if there is a better way. I'm saying there is no cleaner way.